# PHP mutual exclusion (mutex)

Tags: php, mutex, mutual-exclusion

Read some texts about locking in PHP.
They all, mainly, direct to http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php .

This page talks about opening a file on the hard-disk!!

Is it really so? I mean, this makes locking really expensive - it means each time I want to lock I'll have to access the hard-disk )=

Can anymore comfort me with a delightful news?

**Edit:**

Due to some replies I've got here, I want to ask this;
My script will run only by one thread, or several? Because if it's by one then I obviously don't need a mutex. Is there a concise answer?

**What exactly I'm trying to do**

Asked by ircmaxell.
This is the story:

I have two ftp servers. I want to be able to show at my website how many online users are online.
So, I thought that these ftp servers will "POST" their stats to a certain PHP script page. Let's assume that the URL of this page is "http://mydomain.com/update.php".

On the website's main page ("http://mydomain.com/index.php") I will display the cumulative statistics (online users).

That's it.

My problem is that I'm not sure if, when one ftp server updates his stats while another does it too, the info will get mixed.
Like when multi-threading; Two threads increase some "int" variable at the same time. It will not happen as expected unless you sync between them.
So, will I have a problem? Yes, no, maybe?

**Possible solution**

Thinking hard about it all day long, I have an idea here and I want you to give your opinion.
As said these ftp servers will post their stats, once every 60sec.
I'm thinking about having this file "stats.php".
It will be included at the updating script that the ftp servers go to ("update.php") and at the "index.php" page where visitors see how many users are online.
Now, when an ftp server updates, the script at "update.php" will modify "stats.php" with the new cumulative statistics.
First it will read the stats included at "stats.php", then accumulate, and then rewrite that file.

If I'm not mistaken PHP will detect that the file ("stats.php") is changed and load the new one. Correct?

Comment: Does PHP even support threading?  Looking through the PHP API I don't see anything that appears to be thread-related...

Comment: For some reason I thought PHP supports threading, in the manner that it'll execute the same script for several clients simultaneously.

Comment: So I have a static variable which will hold some data, which is updated by several sources and being feed to several clients. This might happen concurrently so therefore I need some way to sync.

Comment: Everyone, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922959/php-rewrite-to-included-file-is-this-a-valid-script .

Comment: @tloach, PHP is a **language**. It can support everything with its extension libraries.

Comment: Locking a file (without necessarily accessing the file) is certainly one way to implement a mutex. But, just for the sake of discussion, what about a two-phase write into a shared memory location? Process/client A writes a unique integer into memory. Then process A reads the unique integer and makes sure it hasn't changed. If so, then A can enter shared code (otherwise, A tries again in a loop). I think this works no matter what process/client B does, or when it does it, so long as process B runs the same algorithm. Freeing the lock just requires a 0 to be written into the shared location.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, most of PHP runs in a different process space (there are few threading implementations).  The easy one is flock.  It's guaranteed to work on all platforms.

However, if you compile in support, you can use a few other things such as the Semaphore extension.  (Compile PHP with --enable-sysvsem).  Then, you can do something like (note, sem_acquire() should block.  But if it can't for some reason, it will return false):

```
$sem = sem_get(1234, 1);
if (sem_acquire($sem)) {
    //successful lock, go ahead
    sem_release($sem);
} else {
    //Something went wrong...
}
```

The other options that you have, are MySQL [user level locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) `GET_LOCK('name', 'timeout')`, or creating your own using something like APC or XCache (Note, this wouldn't be a true lock, since race conditions could be created where someone else gets a lock between your check and acceptance of the lock).

**Edit:  To answer your edited question:**

It all depends on your server configuration.  PHP May be run multi-threaded (where each request is served by a different thread), or it may be run multi-process (where each request is served by a different process).  It all depends on your server configuration...

It's VERY rare that PHP will serve all requests serially, with only one process (and one thread) serving all requests.  If you're using CGI, then it's multi-process by default.  If you're using FastCGI, it's likely multi-process and multi-thread.  If you're using mod_php with Apache, then it depends on the worker type:

1. mpm_worker will be both multi-process and multi-thread, with the number of processes dictated by the ServerLimit variable.
2. prefork will be multi-process
3. perchild will be multi-process as well

**Edit:  To answer your second edited question:**

It's quite easy.  Store it in a file:

```
function readStatus() {
    $f = fopen('/path/to/myfile', 'r');
    if (!$f) return false;
    if (flock($f, LOCK_SH)) {
        $ret = fread($f, 8192);
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($f);
        return $ret;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return false;
}

function updateStatus($new) {
    $f = fopen('/path/to/myfile', 'w');
    if (!$f) return false;
    if (flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        fwrite($f, $new);
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return false;
}

function incrementStatus() {
    $f = fopen('/path/to/myfile', 'rw');
    if (!$f) return false;
    if (flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
        $current = fread($f, 8192);
        $current++;
        ftruncate($f, 0);
        fwrite($f, $current);
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($f);
        return true;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Different process space yet I can have one static variable (aka singleton) which is shared among all clients - how comes?

Comment: This MySQL user level locks is nice but it requires TCP connection and a MySQL machine/instance. Better use the file-based lock.. Thanks though!

Comment: You can't share a variable across multiple instances of php.  Well, you could if you serialized it and stored it in a global store (like APC, memcached, MySQL, etc).  But each "client" would create its own instance.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Regarding your latest edit ("Edit: To answer your second edited question"), are you talking about my "Possible solution" edit?

Comment: !!!!! Warning: File based locks are UNRELIABLE when you're having a website with high load. You can't do mutex on files.

Comment: @Slawek, How so? This is the first time I've heard this, and I can't find anything to support your claim. (They're unreliable on NFS mounts, but that's something else. They're voluntary so there's no guarantee that noone's using the file, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: @ikegami Only "gotcha" I am aware of is scenario where file does not yet exist and gets overwritten.  Still, better to use System V IPC function's [semaphore/mutex](http://in2.php.net/sem).

Comment: @ficuscr, You can't lock a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: Where will you store the stats that the FTP servers are pushing with POST to your update.php file? If it's a local file, than ircmaxell in the second post has answered you. You can do this with a mutex as well - the semaphore functions. Another solution is to use MySQL MyISAM table to store the stats and use something like `update info_table set value = value + 1`. It should lock the table, and serialize your requests, and you will have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created my own simple implementation of a mutex-like mechanism using the flock function of PHP. Of course the code below can be improved, but it is working for most use cases.

```
function mutex_lock($id, $wait=10)
{
  $resource = fopen(storage_path("app/".$id.".lck"),"w");

  $lock = false;
  for($i = 0; $i < $wait && !($lock = flock($resource,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)); $i++)
  {
    sleep(1);
  }

  if(!$lock)
  {
    trigger_error("Not able to create a lock in $wait seconds");
  }

  return $resource;
}

function mutex_unlock($id, $resource)
{
  $result = flock($resource,LOCK_UN);
  fclose($resource);

  @unlink(storage_path("app/".$id.".lck"));

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's true, as PHP is run by Apache, and Apache can organize the threads of execution as it deems the best (see the various worker model). So if you want to access a resource one at a time, you either lock to a file (which is good if you are dealing with cron jobs for example), or you rely on database transaction mechanism, ACID features, and database resources locking, if you are dealing with data.

Answer (score -3):

PHP doesn't support multithreading, every request (and therefore every PHP script) will be executed in only one thread (or even process, depending on the way you run PHP).

Comment: PHP supports multithreading, you can do it easily using asynchronous HTTP.

Comment: Wait, asynchronous HTTP is client side, that doesn't mean that the server side is running multithreaded (each asynchronous request is executed as a single threaded PHP script).

Comment: pcntl_fork will let you do real multithreading, I wonder why nobody ever mentions it.

Comment: No pcntl_fork lets you do multi-processing, not multi-threading. I have some experience with it :) https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon

Comment: Although PHP doesn’t support running multiple threads, it runs in a multi-threaded or multi-process environment.