# How to use monitors in PHP?

Tags: php, monitor

How to use [monitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) in PHP?

Comment: Related (and possible duplicate): [PHP mutual exclusion (mutex)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921469/php-mutual-exclusion-mutex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong but i thought that the server side model of execution of php is single threaded (aka no more than one thread). In fact i think this is one of reasons of PHP's success. If this is the case i doubt is relevant how do you use synchronization primitives in php.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is single threaded so there is no need for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is single threaded, but if you want to have something like mutex between different processes and you use PHP5, you can simply use built-in session locking to achieve this. Just combine session_start and session_commit at correct places.

Comment: Sessions are not meant to be a cross-process mutex.  And they likely shouldn't be abused in such a manor.  There are a few other alternatives, but Sessions are not one of them...